# Placing image on CMS page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, static-block, popup

I want to place an image on the bottom left corner of one CMS page like https://prnt.sc/3EQgzset5OTi . On clicking the image a pop up should appear with the form to fill up.
Any idea how can i place the image on CMS page. The image will remain static on page scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a shot here may be it will work:

Steps
1). Create phtml and write jQuery, HTML and CSS code in it.

2). Include phtml code in your CMS page by using following code:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Webkul_Test::test.phtml"}}
```

Include CMS block in